# Using shared view model between Activity and Fragment but no update is made on the UI

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, viewmodel

I am doing a sign up procedure and it is divided into three steps, so i am using a shared view model between all the three Fragments and the register activity.
What i want to do is after i load the next fragment, i make some UI updates to show an other toolbar, what is working is the replace Fragment and he is acceding the update UI method successfully but no change is made on the UI

```
    override fun navigateToSignUp() {
        setFragment(
            R.id.home_frame,
            SignUpFragment()
        )
        showTitleInToolbarBackParam("Register", true)
    }
```

```
 private fun showTitleInToolbarBackParam(title: String, back: Boolean) {
        Log.e(TAG, "showTitleInToolbarBackParam: ")
        getDataBinding()!!.appbar.toolbar.visibility = VISIBLE
        getDataBinding()!!.homeappbar.homeappbar.visibility = GONE
        getDataBinding()!!.appbar.titleTextView.text = title
        if (back)
            getDataBinding()!!.appbar.backImageView.visibility = VISIBLE
        else
            getDataBinding()!!.appbar.backImageView.visibility = GONE

    }
```

```
class SignUpFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentSignUpBinding>() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: WelcomingViewModel
    override fun setViewModel() {
        viewModel = activity.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this!!).get(WelcomingViewModel::class.java)
        }
    }

    override fun init() {
        getDataBinding().viewModel = viewModel
    }


    override fun getLayoutId(): Int {
        return R.layout.fragment_sign_up
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.itchek.presentation.welcoming.WelcomingViewModel" />
    </data>
```

And in the binding of all the fragments in the XML files i used the same view model

[This is the module that i had with it the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYQnm.png)

Comment: How exactly do you use shared view model? Show examples of how it is instantiated and used.

Comment: i updated my question, my problem is that i can access the method but i can't make any modification in the UI, i did the debugging and the method is accessible, That's the problem, i thought maybe to make a call back and use it between the fragment and the activity but no need to do that while i have a shared view model

Comment: More information is required to proceed with this issue: `R.layout.fragment_sign_up` and `WelcomingViewModel` contents. Why? It is unclear how exactly data binding is implemented between the view model and layout you use.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?  I am running into the same problem.  If I bind my ViewModel to the fragment it is updated but not when the ViewModel is bound to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

The modern way of inflating fragments is [navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started).
Use addOnDestinationChangedListener() function to change title or visibility of toolbar.

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->

    when (destination.id) {
        R.id.navigation_list -> {
            navBar.visibility = View.GONE
            supportActionBar!!.title = "List"
            supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        }
        R.id.navigation_select -> {
            navBar.visibility = View.GONE
            supportActionBar!!.title = "Select"
            supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        }
        else -> {
            navBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            supportActionBar!!.title = getString(R.string.app_name)
            supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
        }
    }
}
```